# A "holomorphic" Peano curve?

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces

A Peano curve is a continuous map $[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ whose image is the whole square.

I would like to know if on can obtain "holomorphic" Peano curves. Namely, is it possible to find a continuous map $\phi$ from the unit disk $|z|\le 1$ to $\mathbb C^1$  such that 
$\phi$ is holomorphic for $|z|<1$ and the image of the boundary $|z|=1$ has non-empty interior in $\mathbb C^1$ under the map $\phi$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here it is:
MR0015154
Salem, R.; Zygmund, A.
Lacunary power series and Peano curves. 
Duke Math. J. 12, (1945). 569–578.

Comment: And here is the link: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.dmj/1077473367

Answer (score 4):

Define $$\phi(z):=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{S^1}(\zeta-z)^{-1}\cdot \varphi(\zeta)d\zeta$$

for $|z|<1$, where $\varphi: S^1\to\mathbb{C}$ is a Peano curve (i.e. its image has nonempty interior), and $\phi(z):=\varphi(z)$ for $z\in S^1$.  [**Edit**: this construction doesn't work because $\phi$, as I defined it, may not be continuous up to the boundary - see the comments]

Comment: In general there is no reason for this function $\phi$ to be contunuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$! For example, if negative terms are present in the Fourier expansion of $g$, then certainly a continuous extension of the Cauchy Transform of $g$ to the circle will not be equal to $g$.

Comment: I see. You are right! I will not delete the answer because it might be an "instructive mistake" (I'm not an analyst, btw) - I will edit adding a disclaimer. 

Comment: @Qfwfq : Yes, it is instructive. Thank you for the edit!